# How can I best "parallelise" a set of four nested for()-loops in a Brute-Force attack?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, brute-force

**I have the following homework task:**
I need to brute force 4-char passphrase with the following mask

> **<kbd>%</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>**

( where **`@`** - is a numeric character, **`%`** - is an alpha character )

in several threads using OpenMP.

Here is a piece of code, but I'm not sure if it is doing the right thing:

```
int i, j, m, n;

const char alph[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const char num[10] = "0123456789";

#pragma omp parallel for private(pass) schedule(dynamic) collapse(4)
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        for (m = 0; m < 10; m++)
            for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
                pass[0] = alph[i];
                pass[1] = alph[j];
                pass[2] = num[m];
                pass[3] = num[n];

                /* Working with pass here */

            }
```

**So my question is** :
How to correctly specify the "parallel for" instruction, in order to split the range of passphrases between several cores?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, in two places you have `alph` where you should have `num`, that's obviously wrong, but that doesn't have anything to do with OpenMP.  The OMP pragma itself appears correct to the (limited) extent of my understanding of OpenMP.  Please show your complete program, and describe in excruciating detail both what you want it to do, and what it actually did instead.

Comment: That would have been more obvious to you if you moved the `pass[0] = alph[i];` etc away from the innermost loop, to just inside the relevant loop.

Comment: @zwol Edited, thanks. That was just a misprint.

Comment: Which is one reason why we ask for the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoaoAlby Again, please show the _complete program_, and describe in excruciating detail both what you want it to do, and what it actually did.

Comment: @WeatherVane If I understand correctly this is not the way how the `collapse` keyword works. To use it all the outer loops must "perfectly nested" (the loop body of the outer loop can consist only of the inner loop).

Comment: @WeatherVane: Moving `pass[0]` into the relevant loop is probably bad design as it prevents the loops from being collapsed, which either leads to a large load imbalance (outer loop parallelized) or high synchronization costs (inner loop parallelized).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty much right, except for using `alph` instead of `num`. If you're able to define the `pass` variable within the loop, that'll save you many a headache.

A full MWE might look like:

```
//Compile with, e.g.: gcc -O3 temp.c -std=c99 -fopenmp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int PassCheck(char *pass){
  usleep(50); //Sleep for 100 microseconds to simulate work
  return strncmp(pass, "qr34", 4)==0;
}

int main(){
  const char alph[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  const char num[11]  = "0123456789";
  char goodpass[5] = "----"; //Provide a default password to indicate an error state

  int i, j, m, n;

  #pragma omp parallel for collapse(4)
  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < 26; j++)
  for (m = 0; m < 10; m++)
  for (n = 0; n < 10; n++){
    char pass[4];
    pass[0] = alph[i];
    pass[1] = alph[j];
    pass[2] = num[m];
    pass[3] = num[n];
    if(PassCheck(pass)){
      //It is good practice to use `critical` here in case two
      //passwords are somehow both valid. This won't arise in
      //your code, but is worth thinking about.
      #pragma omp critical
      {
        memcpy(goodpass, pass, 4);
        goodpass[4] = '\0';
        //#pragma omp cancel for //Escape for loops!
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Password was '%s'.\n",goodpass);

  return 0;
}
```

**Dynamic scheduling**

Using a `dynamic` schedule here is probably pointless. Your expectation should be that each password will take, on average, about the same amount of time to check. Therefore, each iteration of the loop will take about the same amount of time. Therefore, there is no need to use dynamic scheduling because your loops will remain evenly distributed.

**Visual noise**

Note that the loop nest is stacked, rather than indented. You'll often see this in code where there are many nested loops as it tends to reduce visual noise.

**Breaking early**

`#pragma omp cancel for` is available as of OpenMP 4.0; however, I got a warning using it in this context, so I've commented it out. If you are able to get it working, that'll reduce your run-time by half since all effort is wasted once the correct password has been found and the password will, on average, be located half-way through the search space.

**Where the guessed password is generated**

One of the commentors suggests moving, e.g. `pass[0]` so that it is not in the innermost loop. This is a bad idea as doing so will prevent you from using `collapse(4)`. As a result you could parallelize the outer loop, but you run the risk that its iteration count cannot be evenly divided by the number of threads, resulting in a large load imbalance. Alternatively, you could parallelize the inner loop, which exposes you to the same problem plus high synchronization costs each time the loop ends.

**Why `usleep`?**

The `usleep` function causes the code to run slowly. This is intentional; it provides feedback on the effect of parallelism, since the workload is so small.

If I remove the `usleep`, then the code completes in 0.003s on a single core and 0.004s on 4 cores. You cannot tell that the parallelism is even working. Leaving `usleep` in gives 8.950s on a single core and 2.257s on 4 cores, an apt demonstration of the effectiveness of the parallelism.

Naturally, you would remove this line once you're sure that parallelism is working correctly.

Further, any actual brute-force password cracker would likely be computing an expensive hash function inside the `PassCheck` function. Including `usleep()` here allows us to simulate that function and experiment with high-level design without having to the function first.

Comment: Thank you, indeed this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @JoaoAlby: Note that `strncmp` should have been used instead of `strcmp`. Using the `-fsanitize=address` compilation flag helps identify such errors.

Comment: This is a great answer. I was inspired by it to solve the `cancel for` problem. I generalized to any number of digits (n nested loops) and I can cancel the nested loops. Here is my http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e585c176b12bc607.

Comment: @Zboson: That's awesome! You should add (a bunch of) comments to your code explaining the reasoning of the various bits and post it as an answer :-)