# What is the best way to parellize using openMP in c

Tags: c, openmp, nested-loops

I am  beginner in using OpenMP in C. I am trying to parallelize four nested loops. I've read that it's advisable to only parallelize the outer loop but it's taking a very long time.

What is the best way to parallelize the following

```
int nt=2500, nx=400; nz=200; nh=50;

#pragma omp parallel for
for(it=0; it<nt; it++)
for(ix=0; ix<nx; ix++)
for(iz=0; iz<nz; iz++)
for(ih=-nh; ih<=nh; ih++) {
  if (ix+ih<nx && ix+ih>=0 && ix-ih<nx && ix-ih>=0 ) {
    dR[it][ix+ih][iz] += ii[ih+nh][ix][iz]*us[it][ix-ih][iz];
    dS[it][ix-ih][iz] += ii[ih+nh][ix][iz]*ur[it][ix+ih][iz];
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please explain that the, lets say "improvable", indentation is intentional for supporting some kind of parallelisation-specific visualisation. Or fix it, please.

Comment: *it's taking a very long time*  Well, it's doing quite a lot of work.  Do you mean that the parallel version of the code is not materially faster than the serial version ?  Show us some numbers.  That said, I think your time would be well spent digging that complicated `if` statement out and iterating only over those parts of the domain you want to update -- even if that means replacing one 4-deep loop nest with two 2-deep loop nests.

Comment: The best way to parallelize is the way that maximizes the useful work your cpu is able to perform per time unit. Your question does not have the general answer you seem to be looking for. But yes, commonly the outer loop is the best entry point. Nonetheless, as others pointed out: Give us some numbers for comparison, and specify how exactly you measured them.

Comment: I cleaned up your code and used stacked loops instead of nested loops based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48037315/2542702). This is only a visual change.

Comment: you have race conditions on the `ix`, `iz`, and `ih` iterators. Try `#pragma omp parallel for private(ix, iz, ih)`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as data races go, it is unsafe to parallelize loops in a way that causes the same memory location to be accessed by two different threads and at least one access is a write.

You never read and write to the same variable, so it should be *safe* to parallelize every loop. (Not necessarily more efficient though)

---

Your actual loops can also be rewritten.

Your if condition can be written logically as `0 <= ix+ih < nx && 0 <= ix-ih < nx`, or in other words you only want to write between `0` and `nx`.

If we can show that the ranges of `ix+ih` and `ix-ih` is larger than `0` to `nx` we can eliminate the check and manually loop over those ranges.

Examining the loops we see that `0 < ix < nx` and `-nh < ih < nh` which allows us to find the ranges of `ix+ih` and `ix-ih`.

`ix+ih` ranges from `-nh` to `nx + nh` and `ix-ih` ranges from `-nh` to `nx+nh`. Both of these ranges are larger than `0,nx` as long as `nh` is positive and so we don't need to do a check at all. We can just loop from `0` to `nx`.

```
omp_set_nested(1);

#pragma omp parallel for
for(it=0; it<nt; it++) {

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (iy = 0; iy < nx; iy++) {

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(iz=0; iz<nz; iz++) {

            dR[it][iy][iz] += ii[ih+nh][ix][iz] * us[it][ix-ih][iz]  ;
            dS[it][iy][iz] += ii[ih+nh][ix][iz] * ur[it][ix+ih][iz]  ;
         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Excellent points.  An alternative to set_nested could be to use collapse(2) clause on outer loop (removing pragma omp from middle loop), and replace "parallel for" with simd on the inner loop.